# Is the syntax-error tag a useful tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Is the [syntax-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-error) tag a useful tag? Syntax errors in one's code appear to be useless to people searching for questions on the site. They are likely to get closed. And should we really be hunting for syntax errors in other people's code?

Comment: Is that a burnination-request? A retag-request? ...

Comment: Google "contextual tagging" to learn more.

Comment: And should programmers with elementary syntax errors really be wasting their time trying to sort them out on the Internet? Ask a colleague. I would personally regard any member of my team who did this as incompetent.

Comment: The `syntax` tag is also in need of at least a clean-up.

Comment: MSE dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216739/179419

Comment: @Ben that ended up being closed as offtopic since it should be on MSO instead.

Comment: @EJP In most cases, but I will admit I've sometimes been stumped by Ruby errors for example, since a simpel typo can produce **really** strange errors on very strange lines! I am experienced enough to solve them after the initial *'huh? wtf?'*-moment, but I would have much more problems 15 years ago when I was starting out.... IMHO it can be a valid question for a hobby programmer.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker You can say the same for syntax errors in any other programming languages. It doesn't change the fact that it is a trivial issue. If someone doesn't even put the effort into finding his own syntax errors, I don't think we should spend time helping.

Comment: @simonzack In the specific case of Ruby, the errors can be much more confusing than any other language I've ever worked with (unfortunately I don't have examples at hand). Another confusing (& well-known) error might be PHP's `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` (which is a `::`). In any case, it's trivial for you & me, but I don't think it's unreasonable for a new programmer to be "stuck" at a syntax error, nor does it *necessarily* show a lack of effort (although I will admit it often does)... Of course, this doesn't necessarily mean we need a tag for it...

Comment: [another useful question about syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485918/space-before-star-breaks-syntax-in-ruby-multiplication-statement/27485969)